# Testing Hard Drives

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, sata

First off, I hope this is the right location for this question, if not, any guidance on where to go would be greatly appreciated.

I am looking for some equipment to test multiple hard drives. In the past, we used a simple Drive Duplicator and just ran a DOD wipe on it, but that method is horrible on the poor drives.
I have googled my heart out to find some kinda device meant for this, and I know they exist, but I cannot find one.

**What I am looking for:**

- Multiple drive capability (would want to shoot for 5-6+ to be tested simultaneously)
- SATA Drive Type (having the ability to also so SAS with an adapter would be a plus

Let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: You test what? as I would maybe search to buy a tool that wipe the disk, if the disk stay on, SMART clear of error it mean it passed the test :)

Comment: @yagmoth555 I was thinking that, but wont that just test the used sectors, rather then the entirety of the HDD?

Comment: I would the entire drive, you can't predict bad sector